# Java Spring Boot: Reset Password for Web App

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, nullpointerexception

I'm developing a Java Spring Boot Web app where one features is for users to be able to reset their password. The progression is that on the login screen, they click on 'Reset Password' and are taken to forgotPassword.jsp, where they enter their email address. If the email is found in the database, a verification email is sent to their email address where they can click on a link that is supposed to take them to resetPassword.jsp. This is where my issue lies. For some reason, although when I click on the link the address bar says I'm being taken to /resetPassword.jsp?(insert encrypted password here), I am encountering an error where a NullPointerException is occurring, and I'm unsure why. And so I'm unable to reset the password for the user. First, here is forgotPassword.jsp. Notice modelAttribute="user":

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<div id="editAccount">

    <div class="row parentRow">

        <div class="parentCol">

            <div class="panel panel-default"
                style="flex-direction: row; min-width: 60%;">

                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <div
                        style="padding-top: 15%; font-size: x-large; color: black; padding-bottom: 3%;">Reset
                        Password</div>
                </div>

                <div style="flex-grow: 1;">

                    <form:form modelAttribute="user" method="post">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <form:input type="text" name="email" path="email"
                                placeholder="Email Address"
                                style="margin-top: 8%; min-width: 100%;" />
                        </div>

                        <div style="margin-top: 8%; text-align: center; min-width: 100%;">

                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reset"
                                class="suit_and_tie" />

                        </div>

                    </form:form>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Next is the forgotPassword GET and POST Controllers, which seem to be working fine since I'm sent a verification email and a token for the email is created:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/forgotPassword", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayResetPassword(ModelAndView modelAndView, SiteUser user) {
        modelAndView.getModel().put("user", user);
        modelAndView.setViewName("app.forgotPassword");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/forgotPassword", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView forgotUserPassword(ModelAndView modelAndView, @ModelAttribute(value="user") SiteUser user) {
        SiteUser existingUser = userRepo.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
       
        if (existingUser.getEmail() == null) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/invalidUser");
        }
        
        else {
            String token = userService.createEmailVerificationTokenForgotPassword(existingUser).toString();

            emailService.sendVerificationEmailForgotPassword(existingUser.getEmail(), token);
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/verifyEmail");

        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Next, we have resetPassword.jsp, where the user is supposed to enter their new password. Again, notice modelAttribute="user":

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<div id="editAccount">

    <div class="row parentRow">

        <div class="parentCol">

            <div class="panel panel-default"
                style="flex-direction: row; min-width: 60%;">

                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <div
                        style="padding-top: 15%; font-size: x-large; color: black; padding-bottom: 3%;">Enter
                        New Password</div>
                </div>

                <div style="flex-grow: 1;">

                    <form:form modelAttribute="user" method="post">

                        <div class="errors">
                            <form:errors path="message.*" />
                            <form:errors path="user.*" />
                        </div>
                        
                        <form:input type="hidden" path="email" />
                        <form:input type="hidden" path="userId" />

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <form:input type="password" path="plainPassword"
                                placeholder="New Password" method="post"
                                style="margin-top: 8%; min-width: 100%;" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <form:input type="password" path="repeatPassword"
                                placeholder="Repeat Password" class="form-control"
                                style="margin-top: 8%; min-width: 100%;"/>
                        </div>

                        <div style="margin-top: 8%; text-align: center; min-width: 100%;">

                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"
                                class="suit_and_tie" /> 

                        </div>

                    </form:form>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And then here is likely where my issues lie, in the confirmReset controller and resetPassword controller. The confirmReset controller is intended to verify that the user is using the correct email token in order to be able to then access the resetPassword controller. The resetPassword controller will then handle the user's entry of a new password. You will notice my debugging System.out.println() statements in the controllers, where not a single one is shown in the stack trace down below, and so I'm not even getting into confirmReset().

```
@RequestMapping(value="/confirmReset", method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    ModelAndView confirmReset(ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam("t") String tokenString, BindingResult result) {
        
        ForgotPasswordToken token = userService.getForgotPasswordToken(tokenString);
        
        if(token == null) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/invalidUser");
            userService.deleteToken(token);
            System.out.println("*************** ONE ************");
            return modelAndView;
        }
        
        Date expiryDate = token.getExpiryDate();
        
        if(expiryDate.before(new Date())) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/expiredToken");
            userService.deleteToken(token);
            System.out.println("*************** TWO ************");
            return modelAndView;
        }
        
        SiteUser user = token.getUser();
        
        if (user == null) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/invalidUser");
            userService.deleteToken(token);
            System.out.println("*************** THREE ************");
            return modelAndView;
        }
        
        userService.deleteToken(token);
        user.setEnabled(true);
        userService.save(user);
        
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/resetPassword");
        return modelAndView;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/resetPassword", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView resetPassword(ModelAndView modelAndView, @ModelAttribute(value="user") SiteUser user) {

        modelAndView.getModel().put("user", user);
        
        if (userEmail != null)
        {
            SiteUser tokenUser = userRepo.findByEmail(userEmail);
            tokenUser.setPassword(userPW);
            userRepo.save(tokenUser);
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/passwordReset");
            System.out.println("*************** FOUR ************");
        } 
        
        else {
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/invalidLink");
            System.out.println("*************** FIVE ************");
        }
        
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

And then the relevant stack trace for debugging purposes:

```
2020-10-14 11:14:51.376 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-14 11:14:51.377 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-14 11:14:53.424 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/forgotPassword", parameters={masked}
2020-10-14 11:14:53.425 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to bcoreHW.controllers.AuthController#forgotUserPassword(ModelAndView, SiteUser)
2020-10-14 11:14:53.426 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select siteuser0_.user_id as user_id1_3_, siteuser0_.email as email2_3_, siteuser0_.enabled as enabled3_3_, siteuser0_.password as password4_3_, siteuser0_.role as role5_3_ from users siteuser0_ where siteuser0_.email=?
Hibernate: select siteuser0_.user_id as user_id1_3_, siteuser0_.email as email2_3_, siteuser0_.enabled as enabled3_3_, siteuser0_.password as password4_3_, siteuser0_.role as role5_3_ from users siteuser0_ where siteuser0_.email=?
2020-10-14 11:14:53.429 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
2020-10-14 11:14:53.430 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
2020-10-14 11:14:53.433 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into forgot_password (expiry_date, token, token_type, user_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into forgot_password (expiry_date, token, token_type, user_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-10-14 11:14:53.436 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.view.RedirectView        : View name 'redirect:', model {}
2020-10-14 11:14:53.436 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND
2020-10-14 11:14:53.441 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/verifyEmail", parameters={}
2020-10-14 11:14:53.441 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to bcoreHW.controllers.AuthController#verifyEmail()
2020-10-14 11:14:53.442 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2020-10-14 11:14:53.442 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView    : View name 'app.verifyEmail', model {}
2020-10-14 11:14:53.443 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-14 11:14:53.458 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/css/main.css", parameters={}
2020-10-14 11:14:53.458 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/css/bootstrap.min.css", parameters={}
2020-10-14 11:14:53.459 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-10-14 11:14:53.459 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-10-14 11:14:53.459 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/js/bootstrap.min.js", parameters={}
2020-10-14 11:14:53.460 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-10-14 11:14:53.460 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/img/bcore-bride+AI.png", parameters={}
2020-10-14 11:14:53.460 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-10-14 11:14:53.461 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-14 11:14:53.462 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-14 11:14:53.463 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-14 11:14:53.463 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-14 11:15:02.419 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/resetPassword?t=fcdb7577-ddd8-4886-a387-ec36809140fe", parameters={masked}
2020-10-14 11:15:02.420 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to bcoreHW.controllers.AuthController#resetPassword(ModelAndView, SiteUser)


2020-10-14 11:15:02.421 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select siteuser0_.user_id as user_id1_3_, siteuser0_.email as email2_3_, siteuser0_.enabled as enabled3_3_, siteuser0_.password as password4_3_, siteuser0_.role as role5_3_ from users siteuser0_ where siteuser0_.email=?
Hibernate: select siteuser0_.user_id as user_id1_3_, siteuser0_.email as email2_3_, siteuser0_.enabled as enabled3_3_, siteuser0_.password as password4_3_, siteuser0_.role as role5_3_ from users siteuser0_ where siteuser0_.email=?
2020-10-14 11:15:02.422 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Using @ExceptionHandler bcoreHW.controllers.GlobalExceptionHandler#invalidUserMessage(HttpServletRequest, Exception)
2020-10-14 11:15:02.423 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [java.lang.NullPointerException] to ModelAndView [view="app.exception"; model={message=Invalid user., url=http://localhost:8080/resetPassword, exception=java.lang.NullPointerException}]
2020-10-14 11:15:02.423 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Using resolved error view: ModelAndView [view="app.exception"; model={message=Invalid user., url=http://localhost:8080/resetPassword, exception=java.lang.NullPointerException}]
2020-10-14 11:15:02.423 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2020-10-14 11:15:02.423 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView    : View name 'app.exception', model {message=Invalid user., url=http://localhost:8080/resetPassword, exception=java.lang.NullPointerException}
2020-10-14 11:15:02.427 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2020-10-14 11:15:02.443 DEBUG 64667 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/css/bootstrap.min.css", parameters={}
2020-10-14 11:15:02.443 DEBUG 64667 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-10-14 11:15:02.444 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/js/bootstrap.min.js", parameters={}
2020-10-14 11:15:02.444 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/css/main.css", parameters={}
2020-10-14 11:15:02.444 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/img/bcore-bride+AI.png", parameters={}
2020-10-14 11:15:02.444 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-10-14 11:15:02.444 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-10-14 11:15:02.444 DEBUG 64667 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
```

Here then is resetPassword.jsp once I click on the reset link from the email. You can see the password token in the address bar, but I'm still getting the NullPointerException and thusly being shown my handling message "Invalid user."

[image]

Comment: You can post  error stack trace also, so that easy to understand where Null occurs.

Comment: Hmm sorry how do I do this in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm also using https://github.com/ro6ley/java-forgot-pswd as a reference.

Comment: I tried to clone and run, looks like i need to configure database, try to check the stack trace of error and line number.